# Find all $x,y$ so that $\dfrac{x+y+2}{xy-1}$ is an integer.

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am trying to find the integers $x,y$ so that 
$\dfrac{x+y+2}{xy-1}$ is an integer. 
What I have done:
I suppose there exists $t$ such that $$t=\dfrac{x+y+2}{xy-1}$$ where $xy\neq 1$ then consider the following scenarios:
$$x=y$$ $$x>y>0$$  $$x>0>y$$ ,etc.
This approach  helps me find the solutions but it is very long. Any simpler method?

Comment: are $x$ and $y$ integers?

Comment: yes they are integers. i will fix that.

Comment: $x = 2, y = 1$.

Comment: Do you allow negative x or y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=y=-1$, then $x+y+2=xy-1=0$. Therefore, some of the solutions below need to be prefaced with "except for $x=y=-1$".

---

If $x=y$, then $\frac{x+y+2}{xy-1}=\frac{2}{x-1}$, which says that
$$
x=y\in\{0,2,3\}\quad\text{are the only solutions with $x=y$}\tag{1}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
x+y=-2\quad\text{is a solution}\tag{2}
$$
We also have that
$$
xy=0\quad\text{is a solution}\tag{3}
$$
If $x=-1$ or $y=-1$, $\frac{x+y+2}{xy-1}=-1$. Therefore,
$$
(x+1)(y+1)=0\quad\text{is a solution}\tag{4}
$$
If $y=1$, then the solutions to $\frac{x+y+2}{xy-1}=\frac{x+3}{x-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$ must have $-3\le x\le5$. Checking gives
$$
\{(-3,1),(-1,1),(0,1),(2,1),(3,1),(5,1)\}\tag{5}
$$
If $x=1$, then the solutions to $\frac{x+y+2}{xy-1}=\frac{y+3}{y-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$ must have $-3\le y\le5$. Checking gives$$
\{(1,-3),(1,-1),(1,0),(1,2),(1,3),(1,5)\}\tag{6}
$$
Since
$$
|xy-1|-|x+y+2|\ge(|x|-1)(|y|-1)-4\tag{7}
$$
if $x+y\ne-2$ and $(|x|-1)(|y|-1)\ge5$, then $(x,y)$ cannot be a solution. Since all the solutions with $|x|\le1$ or $|y|\le1$ are covered above, we only need to check $2\le|x|,|y|\le5$. Checking these $64$ cases, the only new solutions not counted above are
$$
\{(2,5),(5,2)\}\tag{8}
$$
Therefore, all solutions are given by $(1)$-$(6)$ and $(8)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x>3$ and $y>3$, then the denominator is bigger than the nominator because:

$xy-1-x-y-2 = (x-1)(y-1) - 4 > 2 \cdot 2 - 4 = 0 $

So the given number cannot be an integer.

You can look at the other cases manually:
$0 \le x \le 3$ and $0 \le y \le 3$.

If you allow negative x,y then you can apply similar observations, only the denominator gets changed slightly. Think about it.

Comment: I like so far your approach. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, should you mention that is the case in absolute value?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean in absolute value the numerator must be  greater than the denominator $t$ to be an integer.

Comment: @Ramunjndscpl No, if you allow negatives then you have two cases: exactly one of $x, y$ is negative or both are negative. The former is more difficult, in that case let $a=-x$ and note what happens. Apply a similar argument.

Comment: in your answer, you did mention for $x>3 $ and $y>3$, which is ok since both numerator and denominator are greater than $0$.

Comment: This does not cover all the cases. The negation of $x\gt3$ and $y\gt3$ is $x\le3$ **or** $y\le3$, and not $x\le3$ **and** $y\le3$. There are an infinitude of solutions as given in cases $(2)$-$(4)$ of my answer. There are $10$ other solutions given in my answer not covered in $(2)$-$(4)$; $(1,5)$ and $(2,5)$ are two that are not covered by $x\le3$ and $y\le3$.

Comment: @robjohn Read the two $0 \le x \le 3$ and $0 \le y \le 3$ independently. That's how I meant it, I think. Of course the negation is not an AND but an OR.

Answer (score 2):

Wlog $|x|\le |y|$.

$x=0$ leads to $\frac{y+2}{-1}$, which is always an integer.

$x=1$ leads to $\frac{y+3}{y-1}=1+\frac4{y-1}$ which is an integer iff $y-1$ is a (positive or negative) divisor of $4$, so $y\in\{-3,-1,2,3,5\}$ ($y=0$ is excluded by $|y|\ge |x|$)

$x=-1$ leads to $\frac{y+1}{-y-1}=-1$, always an integer

$|x|\ge2$ leads to $|xy-1|\ge 2|y|-1\ge 3$ and $|x+y+2|\le 2|y|+2$, so that $\left|\frac{x+y+2}{xy-1}\right|\le\frac{2|y|+2}{2|y|-1}=1+\frac{3}{2|y|-1}\le 2$ with equality only for $|x|=|y|=2$. So we need only check the special case $|x|=|y|=2$ and otherwise if the quotient can be $-1$ or $0$ or $1$.

- $(2,2)$ leads to quotient $2$; $(2,-2)$ and $(-2,2)$ lead to $-\frac 25$; $(-2,-2)$ leads to $-\frac 23$
- The quotient is $0$ iff $y=-x-2$.
- The quotient is $1$ iff $x+y+2=xy-1$, i.e., $(x-1)(y-1)=4$; the finitely many factorizations give us finitely many solutions $x=y=3$ or $x=2,y=5$ (all else is exclude by $|y|\ge |x|\ge 2$)
- The quotient is $-1$ iff $x+y+2=1-xy$, i.e., $(x+1)(y+1)=0$ - contradicting $|y|\ge|x|\ge 2$.

So in summary, as solutions $(x,y;\frac{x+y+2}{xy-1})$ we have the families
$$ (0,t;-t-2), (t,0;-t-2), (-1,t;-1),(t,-1;-1),(t,-2-t;0)$$
and the special solutions
$$(1,2;5),(2,1;5),(1,3;3),(3,1;3),(1,5;2),(5,1;2),(2,2;2),(3,3;1),(2,5;1),(5,2;1).$$

Answer (score 1):

For this to happen we need $|x+y+2|\geq |xy-1|$ or $x+y+2=0$.

If $x+y+2=0$ we get solutions $(a,-a-2),(-a-2,a)$.

otherwise we have $|x+y|+2\geq |xy|-1\rightarrow |x|+|y|+3\geq |x||y|$.

Notice that if $x$ or $y$ is $0$ it holds trivially.

We now find all possible values $n,m> 0$ so that $n+m+3\geq nm\iff \frac{n+3}{n-1}\geq m$

If $n=1$ any $m$ works.

If $n=2$ we get $m\leq 5$

If $n=3$ we get $m \leq 3$

If $n=4$ we get $m\leq 2$

If $n=5$ we get $m\leq 2$.

If $n\geq 6$ we get $m=1$.

So we first analyse the case when $|x|=1$.

If $x=1$ we get $y-1$ divides $y+3$, so $y-1$ divides $(y+3)-(y-1)=4$, hence $y-1$ can be $-4,-2,-1,1,2$ or $4$. It is easy to see all of them work. So we get $(1,-3),(1,-1),(1,0),(1,2),(1,3),(1,5)$.

If $x=-1$ we get $-(y-1)$ divides $y-1$. So $y+1$ divides $y-1$ and hence $y+1$ divides $y+1-(y-1)=2$. So $y+1$ can be $-2,-1,1,2$. It is easy to see all of them work. So we get $(-1,-3),(-1,-2),(-1,0),(-1,1)$.

Since $x$ and $y$ play symmetric roles in the equation, this gives all solutions with $|x|=1$ or $|y|=1$.

Now we analyse when $|x|=2$.

If $x=2$ we get $2y-1$ divides $y+4$, we need only try with $y=-5,-4,-3,-2,0,2,3,4,5$. We see only $(2,-4),(2,0),(2,2),(2,5)$ work.

If $x=-2$ we get $-2y-1$ divides $y$, so $2y+1$ divides $y$, and so $2y+1$ divides $2y+1-2(y)=1$. So we only try with $2y+1=1$ and $2y+1=-1$. So $(-1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$ are solutions.

So we only need to check when $|x|,|y|>2$.

If $|x|=3$ we need only check if $|y|=3$. There are four cases, and out of these only $(3,3)$ works.

This finishes all the cases.

(I'll try to make this a bit cleaner when I get home).